# On form submit, scroll to another element in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Depending on values of the options (pictured below) the user selects, I'm trying to scroll to specific part of same page - `.cell ct card-item` when I click on `submit` button. Tried to adapt several solutions posted on similar questions but nothing but errors so far (still very new to this...). As far as I'm aware, the below line of jQuery is still pretty far from where it needs to be. Any advice would be greatly appreciated:

```js
$('html, body').on('submit', animate({
 scrollTop: $(".cell ct card-item").offset().submit
}, 1000));
```

```html
<form id="crsSelectorForm" method="post">
  <div class="" id="ov_mcReq">
    <h3>What language level does your main course require?</h3>
  <label for="mcReq">Overall Requirement: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
     <select id="mcReq" onchange="showMinMcReq();">
       <option value="">Please Select</option>
       <option value="5">5.0</option>
       <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
       <option value="6">6.0</option>
       <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
       <option value="7">7.0</option>
       <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    <div class="ieltsRes_All" id="ieltsRes">
     <h3>Please input your four-skill language test results</h3>
      <label for="curL">Listening: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
       <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_L">
         <option value="">Please Select</option>
         <option value="4">4.0</option>
         <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
         <option value="5">5.0</option>
         <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
         <option value="6">6.0</option>
         <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
         <option value="7">7.0</option>
         <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
         <option value="8">8.0</option>
         <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
         <option value="9">9.0</option>
         <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
       </select>
      <label for="curR">Reading: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
       <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_R">
         <option value="">Please Select</option>
         <option value="4">4.0</option>
         <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
         <option value="5">5.0</option>
         <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
         <option value="6">6.0</option>
         <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
         <option value="7">7.0</option>
         <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
         <option value="8">8.0</option>
         <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
         <option value="9">9.0</option>
         <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
       </select>
      <label for="curW">Writing: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
       <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_W">
         <option value="">Please Select</option>
         <option value="4">4.0</option>
         <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
         <option value="5">5.0</option>
         <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
         <option value="6">6.0</option>
         <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
         <option value="7">7.0</option>
         <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
         <option value="8">8.0</option>
         <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
         <option value="9">9.0</option>
         <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
       </select>
      <label for="curS">Speaking: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
       <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_S">
         <option value="">Please Select</option>
         <option value="4">4.0</option>
         <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
         <option value="5">5.0</option>
         <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
         <option value="6">6.0</option>
         <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
         <option value="7">7.0</option>
         <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
         <option value="8">8.0</option>
         <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
         <option value="9">9.0</option>
         <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
       </select>
      <label for="curOv">Overall: <span class="required">*</span> </label>
       <select class="curScore" id="ieltsRes_Ov" onchange="showSubmit();">
         <option value="">Please Select</option>
         <option value="4">4.0</option>
         <option value="4.5">4.5</option>
         <option value="5">5.0</option>
         <option value="5.5">5.5</option>
         <option value="6">6.0</option>
         <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
         <option value="7">7.0</option>
         <option value="7.5">7.5</option>
         <option value="8">8.0</option>
         <option value="8.5">8.5</option>
         <option value="9">9.0</option>
         <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
       </select>
    </div><br>
     <div class="" id="submit">
      <button type="submit" onclick="ovLangMC();">Submit</button> 
     </div>
   </form>
      
      
<div class="cell ct card-item ">
    <div>
  <a href="https://www.pagelink.com">
           <img class="img-class" src="example.jpg" alt="">             </a>
   <div class="example-class">
              <h3>
                 <a href="https://www.examplepage.com">Title of thing to link to</a>
                </h3>
                    <p>Blah blah blah</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless you're using AJAX to submit the form, this isn't going to work

Comment: Or, you can add `hash` to the `action` url so it will scroll to the element with the corresponding `id` (but without the animation)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll have a look into using AJAX, thanks for suggestion

Comment: Hi Mosh, sorry, not sure I follow - do you mean add action as attr on form?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it can definitely work if the redirect after submission has the `#anchor` at the end of the URL.

Comment: True. Perhaps my initial comment was a bit too definitive. The point is that it's not going to work in the manner the OP is attempting to do it, without AJAX.